# Describe the equivalence classes generated by T

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, equivalence-relations

Suppose $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid y = x + 1\text{ and } 0 < x < 2\}$.

Question
Describe the equivalence relation T on the real line that is the intersection of all equivalence relations on the real line that contain S.

Suppose that
$$A_1 = S$$
$$A_2 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid  y = x - 1 \text{ and } 1 < x < 3\}$$
$$A_3 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid y = x + 2\text{ and } 0 < x < 1\}$$
$$A_4 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid y = x - 2\text{ and } 2 < x < 3\}$$
$$A_5 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x - x = 0\}$$

I proved that $T = \bigcup_{i = 0}^{i = 5} A_i$ I am also pretty sure that my proof is correct. My Question is I want to make sure that I am describing the equivalence classes correctly. Let $E_x$ denote the equivalence class for the element $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $ -\infty < x \leq 0 \text{ and } 3 \leq x < \infty$, then $E_x = \{x\}$.
 If $0 < x < 1$, then $E_x = \{x,x + 1,x+2\}$.

If $x = 2,1,$ then $E_x = \{1,2\}$. If $1 < x <2$, then $E_x = \{x,x+1,x - 1\}$. 
Lastly if $2 < x < 3$, then $E_x = \{x,x - 1,x-2\}$.

Want to make sure I described the equivalence classes correctly.

Comment: I edited your MathJax code for proper use of \mid and \text{}.  Look at it and you'll see how those should be used. $\qquad$

Comment: It seems you forgot $E_0$ and $E_3$

Comment: I also think the OP made an error, I think he/she wanted to state T =$ \cap  {A_i} ^{i=5} _{i=0}$ . Correct?

Comment: No @Mathemagician1234 it is union.

Comment: @MichaelHardy thank you I didn't know that there is something like that!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes I did indeed forget $E_0,E_3$ it should be the singletons though i.e $E_0 = \{0\}$ and $E_3 = \{3\}$. I will edit it.

Comment: @TheKEMO Ok,I wasn't sure,that's why I didn't edit the question myself. I'm not having good success on here lately-I think I'm just distracted and overworked. I shouldn't try and answer more questions until I get past that.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 It is ok. The reason it is the union because we just pick elements of S and make them satisfy the equivalence relation properties, and after some computation we get the sets that I computed above.

Comment: @TheKEMO I can see that now. What I can't see is how this particular union is equal to the intersection of all equivalence relations that contain S.An interesting question:Can we select a topology on the real line that is defined by the equivalence relations where each equivalence relation is a closed set that contains S and therefore T is the closure? That would be a terrific solution if possible.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 want to come to chat we can discuss it.

Comment: @TheKEMO I can't right now. It'll have to wait for another day-maybe I'll post my questions separately and we can discuss it then.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 The reason it is equal to the intersection is because if we pick any equivalence relation that contain S(which a set in the intersection), then it must obey reflexivity,symmetry,transitivity, and must contain S right ? So it must then contain those sets. I am not sure about the topology question I am not there yet.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Alright sounds good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about $T$ and mostly right about the equivalence classes, with only one definite shortcoming:

- You write "If $ -\infty < x \leq 0 \text{ and } 3 \leq x < \infty$" -- this condition is not satisfied by any $x$. What you mean is, "If $ -\infty < x \leq 0$ *or* $3 \leq x < \infty$".

Generally, though, I would note that you're not being asked to describe the equivalence class of $x$ for each $x$ -- just to *describe all of the equivalence classes*, so there's no need to give each of the equivalence classes multiple times just because it has multiple elements. So I would write the result as:

- $\{a\}$ for every $a\in (-\infty,0] \cup [3,\infty)$,
- $\{b,b+1,b+2\}$ for every $b\in(0,1)$, and
- $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, and the answer. I was little bit confused on why $\{1,2\}$ represented all the equivalence class for other elements of x, but after thinking about I understand now. How I extracted the answer was based on geometric picture of graphing the lines and see which y is x related to in the graph, but we have to also think that by symmetry x ~ y, and that is how everything shrinks into the equivalence class $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: @TheKEMO: It's not really "for other elements of $x$" -- merely that _every equivalence class is somewhere in the list_, which it is. For example the equivalence class that contains $1.52$ is the one described by the middle line in the case $b=0.52$. There's no requirement that your description needs to make it easy to go from a number to the particular equivalence class that contains it.

Comment: Oh I understand.